# Toggle an animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, toggle

I'm trying to toggle an animation when the user clicks a link like so:

CSS

```
.men{
    background: url("../img/men4.jpg") no-repeat scroll 16% 0 transparent;
    height: 600px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
}

.women{
    background: url("../img/women1.jpg") no-repeat scroll 84% 0 transparent;
    height: 600px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
}
```

HTML

```
  <div class="men">
    </div> 
    <div class="women">
    </div> 
    <a href="#" class="openmen">Men</a>
    <a href="#" class="openwomen">Women</a>
```

JQUERY

```
$("a.openwomen").click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
            $('.women').animate({width:"80%"}); 
            $('.men').animate({width:"20%"});   
            $('.men').animate({opacity: 0.5}, 500); 
            $('.women').animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
        });
```

but I'm not too sure how to go about it, I want it to go back to it's original state when they click again.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried reading JQuery API Documentation?

[JQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

They show you an easy example of how to use toogle instead of animating each component by yourself.
/******************************************************************************************/

Why don't you try something like this?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
        <head>
         <style>
           div { background:#dad;
           font-weight:bold;
           font-size:16px; }
         </style>
         <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <a href="#">Toggle 'em</a>     
        <div class="toggle_class">Hiya</div>
        <div class="toggle_class">Such interesting text, eh?</div>
        <script>
        $("a").click(function () {
        $(".toggle_class").toggle("slow");
        });
        </script>
        </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: when I add toggle the link seems to disappear for some reason.

Comment: try to add something inside each div, maybe the block is not getting drawn;

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var toggle=1;
$(function() {
    $("a.openwomen").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if(toggle==1)
        {
            $('.women').animate({width:"80%"}); 
            $('.men').animate({width:"20%"});   
            $('.men').animate({opacity: 0.5}, 500); 
            $('.women').animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
        }
        else
        {
            $('.women').animate({width:"50%"}); 
            $('.men').animate({width:"50%"});   
            $('.men').animate({opacity: 0}, 500); //change opacity here as you want
            $('.women').animate({opacity: 0}, 500); //change opacity here as you want
        }
        toogle=(toggle==1) ? 2 : 1;
    });
});
```

More about animation http://api.jquery.com/animate/